# Bootstrap timepicker validations with range selectors

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I want to implement time-picker validations in Bootstrap time-picker with range selectors.
Means start time is less than the end time. And if possible timings available for day periods only.

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <label for='start_time'>Start Time:</label>
    <input id="timepicker1" type="text" name="start_time" class="input-small">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
    <label for='End Time:'>End Time:</label>
    <input id="timepicker2" type="text" name="end_time" class="input-small">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>
```

And jQuery is:

```
<script>
    $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    $('#timepicker2').timepicker();
</script>
```

How would I implement this code for range selectors?

Answer (score 0):

This can help, this is link to jquery forum,

[Jquery Forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-date-range)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-date-range

Comment: sorry this is for datepicker validations, but i want timepicker validations